# How to get a reference to window from a user control using Caliburn Micro

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I want to get a reference from a user control view model to the window that holds the user control. How can I do this?

If I can get a reference to the view from view model then I can use:

```
Window parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(userControlReference);
```

So my questions are:

1. What's the best way to get the reference from user control view model to the window that holds the user control?
2. If I want to use the above code, what is the best way to get a reference to view from view model in Caliburn Micro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A viewmodel will generally inherit from `IViewAware` assuming that it's an `IScreen` implementation

You can just cast a Screen to `IViewAware` and use the `GetView()` method to get a reference to the view. I think you can implement `IViewAware` on your own viewmodels and Caliburn will automatically raise the `ViewAttached` event so you can keep a reference to the view but I might have a look at the docs

Bottom line: check out the IViewAware interface

Edit:

From the docs...

`IViewAware – Implemented by classes which need to be made aware of the view that they are bound to. It has an AttachView method which is called by the framework when it binds the view to the instance. It has a GetView method which the framework calls before creating a view for the instance. This enables caching of complex views or even complex view resolution logic. Finally, it has an event which should be raised when a view is attached to the instance called ViewAttached.`