# TextBox accepts space but rejects numbers and letters...why?

Tags: caliburn.micro

I'm having trouble getting TextBoxes in accept user input in a Caliburn.Micro screen.  I've tried to simplify things as much as possible to get a working (failing) demo.

Here's the view:

`<UserControl x:Class="Bogus.TestView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Enter some text here" />
        <TextBox />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>`

Here's the viewmodel:

```
using Caliburn.Micro;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Bogus
{
    public class TestViewModel : Screen
    {
    }
}
```

I'm activating the screen from within a WinForms control:

```
var w = Caliburn.Micro.IoC.Get<Caliburn.Micro.IWindowManager>();
dynamic settings = new ExpandoObject();
settings.WindowStyle = System.Windows.WindowStyle.ToolWindow;
settings.SizeToContent = System.Windows.SizeToContent.Manual;
settings.Height = 600;
settings.Width = 700;
w.ShowWindow(new TestViewModel(), settings: settings);
```

If I try to type in that textbox, *nothing but spaces* shows up.  Type "Hello World!" and you get a single space, that's it. :(

Oddly, I'm able to activate other screens from this one and I TextBoxes work just fine...but on this screen?  Nothing.

Comment: OK, looks like it has to do with `EnableModelessKeyboardInterop`...but how do I call that frow the WindowManager?  If I call w.ShowWindow() there's no keyboard input; if I call w.ShowDialog() everything works fine.  There's got to be some way to tell the WindowManager it needs to EnableModelessKeyboardInterop for newly created Windows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This SO question was very helpful: [How to get a reference to window from a user control using Caliburn Micro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911074/how-to-get-a-refernce-to-window-from-a-user-control-in-caliburn-micro)

With that idea I was able to do the following to get keystrokes to go through to the new window:

```
w.ShowWindow(viewModel, settings: settings);
var view = viewModel.GetView() as System.Windows.DependencyObject;
var win = System.Windows.Window.GetWindow(view); 
System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(win);
```

Is that the right way to do it?  Is there a better solution?

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you so much for posting this. I just spent 6 hours hunting this one down.